# Return a list after using the pandas filter function

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I am new to Pandas and having some really difficult problems with it.

What I would like to do is group samples by a a value in a respective columns and then run an api calls based on that column value.

That part is done. After the object is created I would like to return the objects and store it to a local variable is proving the challenging part.

Here is my data set that comes in a .CSV file.

```
    Sample  Sample Type Tumor   Age Location
       1       Blood    Benign  43   LUNG
       2       FFPE     Benign  23   LUNG
       3       Blood    Benign  12  LUNG
```

I am filtering the Sample Type of either Blood or FFPE and then applying a function to create the samples

```
def create_samples(x):

    sample_objects = Sample.create({
        'count': x.shape[0],
        'type': x.iloc[0]['Sample Type']
    })

    return sample_objects

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    blood_samples, ffpe_samples = df.groupby('Sample Type').filter(lambda x: create_samples(x))
```

It iterates through the functions twice because there are two SampleTypes, I believe it creates the Blood Samples first and then creates the FFPE Samples second.

In both time the object is created I want to return those objects to a variable blood_samples and variable_samples respectively. Is this possible to do so?

My only hack I can think of is to assign some global variables which I am hoping to avoid.

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `groupby.filter` wrong.  In a `groupby` context, `filter` takes a function that returns a boolean value.  The result is a combined dataframe that only consists of the groups in which the function returned `True`

What you want is this

```
blood_samples, ffpe_samples = (create_samples(d) for _, d in df.groupby('Sample Type'))
```

And this only works when there are exactly two unique values in `df.Sample`

It might be better to leave it as a dictionary

```
sample_dict = {n: create_samples(d) for n, d in df.groubpy('Sample')}
```

Comment: Thank for you that, I was stuck on this for hours. I originally avoided the groupby because it was iterating through the first row twice and creating double samples. I don't know why it is doing it now?